# bootstrap two col-md , want to show the same line

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

loading my web page, I want to see these results. 
   Products Quantity:---?---
 (inline)
   Product Size:---?---(inline)

But my result like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slq54.jpg)

```
  <div class="test">
                <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
                    <label class="col-md-5">Products Quantity</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7"><!-- col-md-7 Begin -->
                        <select name="product_quantity" class="form-control"><!-- form-control Begin -->
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select><!-- form-control Finish -->
                    </div><!-- col-md-7 Finish -->
                </div><!-- form-group Finish -->



                <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
                    <label class="col-md-5 ">Product Size</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7"><!-- col-md-7 Begin -->
                        <select name="product_size" class="form-control"><!-- form-control Begin -->
                            <option>Select a Size</option>
                            <option>Small</option>
                            <option>Medium</option>
                            <option>Large</option>
                        </select><!-- form-control Finish -->
                    </div><!-- col-md-7 Finish -->
                </div><!-- form-group Finish -->
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand. What is the expected outcome? There are many people on SO that would love to help! Help us help you by providing a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to have it as an appended element

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Products Quantity</span>
  </div>
  <select name="product_quantity" class="form-control">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```